# Use a Custom Label in a Custom Link/Button

Tags: custom-button

Is there a way to use a custom label in a javascript custom button ?

for example:

```
var targetUrl = encodeURI("http://{!$Label.targetHost}/what/ever?user={!$User.Username}");
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That should work fine. I just tested in my org with a custom label called Label with the following Javascript on a custom button:

```
alert('{!$Label.Label}');
```

The text I had set up was 'Sample' and when I clicked the custom button on my object it correctly alerted the word Sample.

Are you experiencing something different?

Comment: Thanks for making me test again: be sure to use the right label name !

Comment: No problem. Happens to the best of us! Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 3):

This will work, since before displaying web page, all labels tags -

`("{!$Label.labelName}")`

will be replaced with text values. On page load, javascript will be executed with text values.

Although in your example, I would consider using [custom settings](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/apex_methods_system_custom_settings.htm?SearchType=Stem) for storing variables such as target host.

Comment: Custom Settings or labels both work. One benefit of labels is that they are included in the metadata when you refresh sandboxes or create a package.