# permission set in custom button

Tags: soql, javascript

I had to throw error messages based on permission sets in a custom button.
So i did it like below,

```
var result = 
    sforce.connection.query(
        "SELECT Id " +
        "FROM PermissionSetAssignment " +
        "WHERE PermissionSetId = '0paahhysgshj768' " +
        "AND AssigneeId = '{!$User.Id}'"
    );

   var psAssignment = result.getArray("records");
   if(psAssignment.length === 0){ 
      alert('You dont have access to this functionality.'); 
   }
```

This works fine.
But how can I avoid hardcoding the Permissionset Id in the query.
I know we can store it in custom labels and use it. But, is there any way I can do this by permission set name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SoQL,

```
[SELECT PermissionSetId, PermissionSet.Name
FROM    PermissionSetAssignment
WHERE   AssigneeId = :UserInfo.getUserId()
AND     PermissionSet.Name = 'A Name'];
```

is perfectly acceptable. It should also be ok in a custom button.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is put the Id in Custom Label and then access the custom label in custom button. Thanks .

[Use a Custom Label in a Custom Link/Button](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/7961/use-a-custom-label-in-a-custom-link-button)

Comment: Ya I know i have that option open, but I want a way to query based on permissionsetname